# How to know which sub folder of a wildfly project is used in production

Tags: wildfly

I was given the source code of a wildfly project. Under the top folder, I see 2 folders with almost same names but version numbers. But I can't find which one of the 2 is used. The 2 folders have almost same code for authentication. Please give me how to find which one is used in the production. Or some hint I can try. Thank you very much in advance.